# J2EE EJB Module - Can I run under Weblogic 9 and or 10

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic9.x, ejb-2.x

I have some legacy J2EE EJB Modules (some are EJB 1.1 and Some 2.0)

Can I deploy and run these on weblogic 9 and 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Weblogic 9 is EJB 2.1 compatible. Same goes for WLS 10.
Weblogic 10 supports fully EJB 1.1

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic 9 does not support EJB 3 however Weblogic 10 does.